# Get relative data with max in mysql

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table called log_payment that has a series of payment records like:

```
log_user_id, log_date, log_payment_id

13, 2013-01-01 01:13:00, TRIAL<BR>
13, 2013-01-02 01:18:00, 1<BR>
13, 2013-01-03 01:05:00, 2
```

What I want to get is the payment id and date of the users last record. So I want that user_id's last transaction was 01/03 and has a payment id of 2. So I wrote this query:

```
select max(log_date) as max_date,log_user_id,log_payment_id from log_payment group by log_user_id
```

but it returns `13, 2013-01-03 01:05:00, TRIAL`

So based on some data I found somewhere else, I tried this:

```
select log_user_id, max_date, log_payment_id from (select log_user_id,max(log_date) as max_date from log_payment group by _log_user_id) payment_table inner join log_payment on payment_table.log_user_id = log_payment.log_user_id and payment_table.max_date = log_payment.log_date
```

But this goes on for several minutes until I finally just cancel it.  What am I missing?

Comment: try to let it run all the way through

Answer (score 1):

Your query, which I have reparsed, looks good, except for the _log_user_id in the group by. It should be log_user_id:

```
 select log_user_id, 
        max_date, 
        log_payment_id from 
        (select log_user_id,max(log_date) as max_date from log_payment group by _log_user_id)
              payment_table 
        inner join 
        log_payment 
        on payment_table.log_user_id = log_payment.log_user_id and 
           payment_table.max_date = log_payment.log_date
```

Depending on the size of your tables the query might be slow. Try adding a LIMIT 10 at the end of the query to see if that gets you the desired result for the first 10 tuples.

--dmg

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for the Group by order is use a subquery to make the order by for you:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `log_payment` t1
WHERE `id` = (
    SELECT `id`
    FROM `log_payment` `t2`
    WHERE `t2`.`log_user_id` = `t1`.`log_user_id`
    ORDER BY `t2`.`log_date` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

It also should be really fast. Of course it always relies on your index's setup.